# Access common functions static?

Tags: java, android

I have a question which might be more general, but I came across it during android dev:

How can I best share own common used methods?
Eg retrieving a shared preference by key is always the same code. But if I have to use it in different Fragments or Activities, I always have to copy the same code:

```
private void setSharedPrefs(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value).commit();
}
```

It it a good habit to make this a `public static` in a GlobalUtils class or so?
How would you handle these kind of functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could make it public static:

```
public static void setSharedPrefs(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value).commit();
}
```

Be careful in some situations where you may hold onto the context after an activity has died, that is bad.

A more likely scenario your describing could be to create a class like this:

```
public class MyPrefs {

     SharedPreferences settings;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


     public MyPrefs(Context context){
        settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = settings.edit();
     }

     public void saveName(String name){
          editor.putString("name", name).commit();
     } 

}
```

You would lazy init this class in your class that extends Application and have a getter in there to retrieve it, with something like:

```
 MyPrefs prefs = ((MyAppication) getContext().getApplicationContext()).getMyPrefs();
```

and use it like so:

```
 prefs.saveName("blundell");
```

*EDIT*

Example of Lazy initialisation:

```
private MyPrefs prefs;

public MyPrefs getMyPrefs(){
     if(prefs == null){
          prefs = new MyPrefs(this);
     }
     return prefs;
}
```

**N.B** This is lazy initialization within a class that extends `Application` therefore `this` refers to your application context and will live for the duration of your Application. If you where using an Activity context you would not want to use lazy initialisation. (**So use the application context!**)

Comment: This seems very suitable. But what do you mean with lazy init? I think I have to init by: `MyPrefs prefs = new MyPrefs(context); ... prefs.saveName(..);`

Comment: Lazy init means you don't initialize an instance of this until you actually need it.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely make a static class such as GlobalUtils or even a dedicated class for `SharedPreferences`. You just have to pass in a `Context` to the method so that you could get the `SharedPreferences` object. You can take this as far as you need it to go; I've made these classes countless times. I even have a thread-safe `SharedPreferences` wrapper :-)

**EDIT:** Just looked at my code again and half of my `SharedPreference` wrappers are static and the rest are lazily instantiated. That being said I think you should do whichever you feel comfortable with as long as the rest of your code doesn't necessitate it going one way or the other.

Comment: Warning: this can be a code smell if abused.  Try keeping this stuff _organized_ as much as possible, rather than dumping everything and the kitchen sink into a "utils" class.

Comment: I like to keep my utils classes separate even if there's only a few of them and they're very small but some people like to have a "GlobalUtils" class if it's small enough

Answer (score 0):

I usually write common code inside a static method in a different class. So that i can call the static method anywhere in the project without every time creating new class objects.